# Why does the Hall Coefficient not hold for certain metals?

Tags: solid-state-physics, quantum-hall-effect

We know metals have electrons as their main charge carriers, so we can arrive at the conclusion that $R_H$ is negative.

$R_H=\frac{1}{q n}$, where $q$ is the charge of carriers, which is negative for electrons, and $n$ the charge carrier density, some positive number.

Nevertheless, some metals such as aluminium and magnesium exhibit positive $R_H$ values.  My suspicion is that for these metals, holes are the primary charge carriers.  Is this true?

Comment: If I remember correctly it's due to the fact that in e.g Al the free electron approximation is invalid. The direction of the magnetic force acting on the charge carriers is determined by the sign of the charges _and_ by the curvature of the conduction band, which in many real metals is negative at the Fermi level. For free charges with $E_k \sim k^2$ the curvature is always positive.